# Knockout.js: Updating objects loaded with mapping plugin

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to render a table containing a list of objects my server is sending me. I'm currently doing this:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: services">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: status"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the Knockout.js binding part:

```js
var mappedData = komapping.fromJSON('{{{ services }}}');
ko.applyBindings({services: mappedData});
```

`services` is a variable containing JSON data and the whole page is rendered with handlebars. *So far so good*. I'm able to render the data received in the table.

Now the problem: I'd like to receive a notification which tells me that the status of a service has changed, and update the corresponding object within mappedData. **The problem is that mappedData seems pretty opaque and I'm unable to retrieve an object and update it given its id**.

Help appreciated!

Comment: how is the status getting updated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mappedData` variable at this point will be a knockout array with a bunch of objects that contain knockout observables.

So all you have to do is change the status observable in the correct object from the array.

```
function updateServiceStatus(id, status) {
    var service = mappedData().filter(function(e) { return e.id() == id; });
    if (service.length) { 
        service[0].status(status); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, this works. I'm not sure why I have to call the `mappedData()` object before I filter it though. KO documentation seems a little thin on this topic.

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html - it contains a list of all the properties you can call straight on the observableArray. Filter isn't one of them, because the result can change based on the contents of the array (so, for instance, it wouldn't update a computed). You need to call `mappedData()` to resolve the array value from the observable, then call `filter(...)` on the plain JS array.

Answer (score 0):

To get the object, you can write a helper function that will retrieve for you a service object. You could do something like this (assuming mappedData is an observableArray and id observable) :

```
function get_service_by_id(service_id){
    for(var i=0;i<mappedData().length;i++){
        if (mappedData()[i].id() === service_id){
            return mappedData()[i];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi Bogdig, thanks for the reply. Your solution works, although I kind of prefer the syntax provided by Richard.